# SVG rendering differs between Safari/Chrome/Firefox

Tags: django, svg, matplotlib, safari

I am dynamically generating a figure as part of a website.  The figure is generated by `matplotlib` as part of a Django view function.  Within the view function, I render the figure as an SVG and then add that SVG's content to the view's context and then render a very simple template using that context.  It's a graph of temperature over time from a particular sensor.

When I view the page in a browser, everything works right, in general terms: the graph is shown in the right place and generally shows the right info.  But the image looks different when viewed in Safari vs either Chrome or Firefox.

Here's how it looks in Chrome/Firefox:
[image]

And here's how it looks in Safari:
[image]

A link to the SVG itself is [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/368914/graph.svg).

Here's the code that is generating the SVG:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from mysite.models import TempReading, TempSeries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
import seaborn as sbn
import StringIO

class TestView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'mysite/test.html'
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        upstairs = TempSeries.objects.get(name='Upstairs')
        upstairstemps = upstairs.tempreading_set.all().order_by('-timestamp')

        frame = pd.DataFrame(list(upstairstemps.values()))
        frame.set_index('timestamp', inplace=True)

        fig = Figure()
        ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
        frame['value'].plot(ax=ax)
        ax.get_xaxis().grid(color='w', linewidth=1)
        ax.get_yaxis().grid(color='w', linewidth=1)

        fig.set(facecolor='w')
        canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)

        imgdata = StringIO.StringIO()
        canvas.print_svg(imgdata)

        imgstr = imgdata.getvalue()

        context = super(TestView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['svgtext'] = imgstr

        return context
```

Any thoughts on why the SVG would render differently in different browsers?

Comment: Try explicitly setting a stroke-width on your grid lines.  Stroke width is *supposed* to be 1 by default, but that's no guarantee (I'm not on a Mac so can't test myself).  Another possibility is that the clipping paths are being rendered incorrectly.  Are you able to find the grid lines in the DOM inspector?  And if so, what dimensions does it give you? And are there any errors listed in the styles?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow.  The lines above that start `ax.set_` both explicitly set a `linewidth` for the gridlines.  With the `linewidth` set to 1 as above, no gridlines appear in Safari, but nice clean gridlines appear in Chrome.  If I explicitly set `linewidth=10` for either or both axes, Chrome respects the setting and shows very wide gridlines, while Safari continues to show no gridlines at all.

Comment: That's odd.  The actual SVG file (which is what I was looking at) doesn't have a stroke-width property for the grid lines.  Maybe the library internally knows that the default is 1 so doesn't bother to add a style in that case.  Regardless, that was only a shot in the dark.  Hopefully someone who actually has access to Safari can be more helpful.

Comment: This is my first question on anything like this topic.  Seems not to be getting a lot of interest.  Is the question clear above/is the problem accurately described?

Comment: Unfortunately, I think there's a very narrow group of people who are going to be familiar/interested in the topic and access to the correct OS to test.  A suggestion in the meantime: see if you can create a simple version of the SVG that has the same problem (just start with the file created by matplotlib and delete extra elements until you just have a coloured background and a single gridline).  I'm not familiar with matplotlib myself, but the code it's creating has lots of extra empty elements which might be causing problems.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Really appreciate the advice.

Comment: curious if you ever got to the bottom of this? I am also having a problem and wondering if the stroke width was your issue?